# How to auto-trim scanned images using imagemagick or graphicsmagick?

Tags: imagemagick, scanning, graphicsmagick

I've got some scanned images in *.jpg format. They are scanned using A4 scanner, in greyscale or colour. Scanned pages have very different dimensions - some A5, some A6, some business cards etc. Scanner cover is white.

I want to trim all the white borders using imagemagick or graphicsmagick (those tools, because I want to further batch-process it). I understand that the border is scanned, so not perfecty white and that sometimes can cause trimming too much or too less of the image. However using trim parameter with fuzz I always get too big image. For example, using image of business card below:

```
gm.exe convert -crop -fuzz 50% 01-pixelated.jpg 01-pixelated-gm.jpg
```

produces image which is still not cut from the right and bottom. The result is the same no matter what number I put to the -fuzz parameter.

Could you please test it and advise the command line that will do the job?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to trim right to the edges of the text / content, or to the edges of the piece of paper, whichever size it is (A4, A5, A6)?  In your example, the bottom boundary of the card is not visible at all--I don't know how you expect to detect it.

Comment: I want it to be trimmed to the edges of the content.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97695/is-there-a-lightweight-tool-to-crop-images-quickly || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098965/using-imagemagick-how-do-i-crop-out-the-white-background

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In ImageMagick try this command:

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 80% -trim +repage output.jpg
```

I tested it with ImageMagick 6.4.4 Q16 and, starting from the image you linked, I obtained this output image:

[image: output]

Comment: so obvious, I mismatched -trim with -crop. Thank you!